# запрос в postman выводит ошибку 404 не реагируя на данные

Tags: веб-программирование, request

есть документация API сайта , и в нем прописаны входные данные методом **POST**. 
  Запрос выводит ошибку 404, не пойму в чем проблема.   Ответ должен быть json Подскажите пожалуйста.
[image: что-то пошло не так]()[![введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 404 означает, что ресурса по которому вы обращаетесь не существует. Может быть опечатка в запросе, либо сервер, который раньше отвечал на эти запросы сейчас не работает.